# Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table' again

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Im at the old known problem 'Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. logistic-inventory.component.ts(39, 8): Error occurs in the template of component LogisticInventoryComponent.'

So i did everything i found on StackOverflow and also tried to make it 1:1 to the newest Angular Materials tutorial. Nothing helped and this time i dont know how to fix this.

My HTML ([dataSource]="dataSource" is my Problem):

```html
<html>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">


  <!-- Image Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Artikelbild">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Artikelbild </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> <img id="itemImage" src="{{item.itemImage}}" /> " </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

My app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

/*
  The following imports are Components.
  For a better overview, please sort them below
*/
import { AppComponent } from './index/app.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { LogisticInventoryComponent } from './logistic-inventory/logistic-inventory.component'
/*
  ---------------------------------------------------
*/
/*
  The following imports are from Angular Materials
*/
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
/*
  ---------------------------------------------------
*/
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    LogisticInventoryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    //ANGULAR MATERIALS
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatTableModule,

    //-----------------
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The LogisticInventoryComponent is my problem, even if i delete the MatTableModule out of it, the problem is the same so it seems like it cant reach the import? A import in the logistic*.ts file also not worked.

My logistic *.ts file:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logistic-inventory',
  templateUrl: './logistic-inventory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logistic-inventory.component.scss'],
})
export class LogisticInventoryComponent {

    displayedColumns = ['Artikelbild', 'Artikelname', 'Fach', 'Bestand'];
    dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

    constructor(){

    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  
    }
}
```

My routing module

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './index/app.component';
import { LogisticInventoryComponent } from './logistic-inventory/logistic-inventory.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'inventory', component: LogisticInventoryComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I hope its not a Angular v.16 problem and someone knows how to solve it

I already tried to import MatSortModule, CdkTable, use <mat-table instead of <table mat-table. Nothing of them worked. I also tried to create a mat table in other components, but there is the same behavior.

Comment: That's strange, that error usually happens when a variable is bind in the template but there is no matching variable in the component, make sure that variable has same name in both ends. Your imports looks ok from what you pasted

Comment: @serrulien everything seems to be totally okay... Could that be because of an new version of Angular?

Comment: Tried Angular 15, error was still there.

Comment: Hi, all i can see right now is that you are missing implementation of angular interfaces. like AfterViewInit in your case.

Comment: This does not change anything, but thank you :)